# Zooming an application

Tags: java, android

I've one application in running successfully. I've installed this to my device (Samsung Galaxy SII) also. But, i can't view this application in zoom view. How can i view this? If possible means tell me how? Otherwise, tell the another way to proceed this? Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please provide specific info not overview

Comment: Now, i want use my application also zoom view. How can i use this? Could you please tell me?

Comment: What do you want to xoom in your application? Text, images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In menifest you should provide **supports-screens** attribut for application

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html

Comment: If you've some example for this zooming an application, Please give me?